# attribute lookup str and objects like object.myvar

Tags: python, concatenation

I want to know how i can concat object fields with a variable, it's hard to explain to me, let me give an example

Example:

My object have:

```
myobject.name = 'Red'
myobject.lastname = 'Foo'
```

and I have a function like this:

```
my function
..........
some_dumb_field = name

print myobject.some_dumb_field
```

And this crashes!, how can i concat the str of the field like an object?

Comment: Please post complete code.  What you have makes no sense.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm guessing you are looking for [getattr](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#getattr):

```
print getattr(myobject, some_dumb_field)
```

This will look up the attribute of `myobject` whose name is given by the string `some_dumb_field`.

For example,

```
getattr(myobject, 'name')
```

is equivalent to

```
myobject.name
```

(Warning: This could be called attribute lookup; you won't find it under the term "concat".)

Comment: That's fine! But how can i do for example myobject.name = 10 ? If i do getattr(myobject, 'name') = 10 it gaves me an error! :(

Comment: Ok, was with setattr(x, 'foobar', 123) ;D